# Bottoms fixed footer but not sticky

Tags: html, css

Hello friends i want a footer whos fixed on bottom of page but not sticky or not always on footer just last on wrapper content my footer is fine on small wrapper content but on large wrapper content it fixed on center of content as screen height size. Following is my code snippet

```css
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 5em;
}
#footer {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom:
  0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright
  bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the
  bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally
  pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts
  at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always
  fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using
  some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and
  see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway.
  I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for
  the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site
  have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc.
  Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside
  of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most
  people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's
  container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people
  can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom
  using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right
  now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on
  anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and
  CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container
  to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have
  a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen
  size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included
  is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer
  out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick
  so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom
  regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples
  right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway.
</div>
<div id="footer">
  This is footer
</div>
```

this is for small content

```css
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 5em;
}
#footer
{
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    
    Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway.

</div>
<div id="footer">
    This is footer
</div>
```

Comment: Use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`. Check [CSS Tricks: Sticky Footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) too. `:)`

Comment: i also use position: fixed but it makes my footer sticky and i dont want sticky footer.

Comment: Tell me clearly, what exactly you wanna do when there's less content and long content? Where the footer should come?

Comment: as you see my code snippet my red footer is on middle on content this happen when i use position:absolute; but on position:absolute my footer perfct on bottom on small content, or when i use position: relative; it show my footer perfect on large content but on small content it just bottom on content not on screen bottom.

Comment: i want my footer should be on bottom but on both small content or large content if large content footer show at the end of page by scroll not sticky or on small content footer also show on end of page bottom not end or content div.

Comment: **I said `position: fixed`. When did I say `relative`?**

Comment: yes you are right you not said relative i just share my experience what i was done, or as you said fixed i also try fixed but it convert my footer on sticky footer which is not want.

Comment: I am literally confused on what you expect. `:(`

Comment: i add another code snippet above you can see that in first snippt footer on middle of screen or on second snippt footer is ok on bottom of screen both snipt have same css, I just want that my footer also looks ok on first snippt like second one but not by use position:fixed.